# ¿Por qué no puedo leer el archivo csv con este código?

Tags: java, excepciones

En esta clase de Java, aunque está incompleta, debería por lo menos poder leerse el archivo, el cual está incrustado en Netbeans. He probado todas las rutas posibles, y en todas he obtenido el mismo resultado. El código es el siguiente:

```
public class FicherosCSV {
    /**
     * Metodod para leer el archivo CSV
     * @author: vsaez
     * 
     * @param ruta, separador
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */

    public static void leerArchivoCSV(String ruta, char separador) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception{
        if(ruta == null){
            throw new Exception("DEBE INGRESAR UN NOMBRE Y TIPO DE SEPARADOR");

        }
        System.out.println("ENTRA");



        BufferedReader lectura= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ruta));
        //Para leer la primera linea deñl archivo
        System.out.println("BUFER");
        String linea = lectura.readLine();

        int longitud = 0;
        String errorTipoUno = "A contact with the same email and "
                + "without id Oracle already exists in the system";
        String nuevoArchivo = "nuevo_archivo";

        System.out.println("LEEEE");
        int i = 0;
        while(linea != null){

            //Separamos la linea con el separador
            String[] camposArchivo = linea.split(String.valueOf(separador));
            longitud = camposArchivo.length;
            if(camposArchivo[longitud - 1].contains(errorTipoUno)){

                //SE DEBERIA CREAR OTRO ARCHIVO CSV


            }
            System.out.println(camposArchivo[i]);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(camposArchivo));

            //Seguimos leyendo lineas, hasta que se cumpla la condición del
            //bucle

            lectura.readLine();
            i++;
        }

        //Cerrar el flujo de lectura


            lectura.close();

    }

    /**
     * Metodo para crear ficheros segun el tipo de error
     * @author:  vsaez
     * @param: String que indica el tipo de error
     * @return void
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FicherosCSV f = new FicherosCSV();
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        try {
            f.leerArchivoCSV("‪‪C:\\Users\\gelorduy\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FicherosCSV\\src\\ficheroscsv\\pruebaCSV.txt",',');
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Logger.getLogger(FicherosCSV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Y me aparecen las siguientes excepciones:

> ene 10, 2018 3:49:27 PM ficheroscsv.FicherosCSV main GRAVE: null
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   ‪‪C:\Users\gelorduy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FicherosCSV\src\ficheroscsv\pruebaCSV.txt
>   (El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la
>   etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)   at
>   java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)     at
>   ficheroscsv.FicherosCSV.leerArchivoCSV(FicherosCSV.java:44)   at
>   ficheroscsv.FicherosCSV.main(FicherosCSV.java:96)

El fichero CSV se encuentra dentro de NetBeans.

Comment: ¿Seguro que tienes ese fichero en esa ruta: **`C:\Users\gelorduy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FicherosCSV\src\ficheroscsv\pruebaCSV.txt `**? Yo lo dudo.

Comment: Gracias. Lo intentaré. Un saludo, y muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Usa este codigo para leer cualquier archivo de texto plano

```
public void cargarArchivo(String direccion){
List<String> lineas = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    Path ruta = Paths.get(direccion);

    Stream<String> flujoFormateado = Files.lines(ruta, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // cargando el archivo plano
    flujoFormateado.forEach(lineas::add); // almacenando todos los elementos para su analisis

    System.out.println("lineas guardadas: "+lineas.size());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Archivo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto. Muchas gracias a todos y todas por vuestra ayuda. La solución consistia simplemente en copiar la ruta desde Properties (pulsar botón derecho sobre el archivo y aparece la opción Properties).

Un saludo y gracias de nuevo